# Python foo > bar(input file, output file)

Tags: python

It's propably very basic question but I couldn't find any answer. Right now I have something like:

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]
outFile = sys.argv[2]
with open(inFile, 'r+') as input,open(outFile,'w+') as out:
            #dosomething
```

I can run it with 
`./modulname foo bar` (working). How can I change it so it will work with `/.modulname foo > bar`? (right now it gives me following error).

```
./pagereport.py today.log > sample.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pagereport.py", line 7, in <module>
    outFile = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
./modulname foo > bar
```

`>` is acted upon by shell, and duplicates the STDOUT stream (FD 1) to the file `bar`. This happens before the command even runs, so no, you can't pass the command like that and have `bar` available inside the Python script.

If you insist on using `>`, a poor man's solution would be to make the arguments a single string, and do some string processing inside, something like:

```
./modulname 'foo >bar'
```

And inside your script:

```
infile, outfile = map(lambda x: x.strip(), sys.argv[1].split('>'))
```

Assuming no filename have whitespaces, take special treatment like passing two arguments in that case.

Also, take a look at the `argparse` module for more flexible argument parsing capabilities.

Comment: I guess I need to learn bash. I've misunderstood the requirements of my task.It was supposed to work with "foo > bar " command and I've thought I need to write the data to the second file directly in my app. Now I just print it instead of writing to a file so it works nicely with this ">" shell command.Thanks for the clarification:) This "duplication" made me to think about that.

Answer (score 2):

You could skip the second open (`out`) and instead use `sys.stdout` to write to.

If you want to be able to use both ways of calling it, `argparse` has a comfortable way of doing that with `add_argument` by combining `type=` to a file open for writing and making `sys.stdout` its default.

Answer (score 0):

What error have you got?

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]
outFile = sys.argv[2]
with open(inFile, 'r+') as in_put ,open(outFile,'w+') as out:
    buff = in_put.read()
    out.write(buff)
```

I try to run you code, but you have no `import sys` , so after fixed it as above . I can run it as a simple `cp` command.

```
python p4.py p4.py p4.py-bk
```